# Binding to CollectionViewSource inside grid

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a Pivot view with a couple of pivots like this

```
 <Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding Pivots}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PivotTemplate}" />
```

My ItemTemplate is like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PivotTemplate"
              x:DataType="viewModels:MainPagePivot">
    <PivotItem>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
               <CollectionViewSource x:Name="documents"
                                     Source="{x:Bind DocumentGroups}" 
                                     IsSourceGrouped="True"
                                     ItemsPath="Documents" />
            </Grid.Resources>
            <SemanticZoom Grid.Row="1">
                <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView >
                    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource documents}}" />             
                </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            </SemanticZoom>
        </Grid>
    </PivotItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I have multiple `pivot` items the reference `Binding Source={StaticResource documents}}` always reference the first of my pivots.

Any way to get it to reference the to current iteration? Maybe make the `CollectionViewSource` name dynamic and the deference ditto?

Comment: Where\what is the static resource 'cvsGroups'

Comment: That was a pasting error. I  have fixed it now.

Comment: First, remove the `<PivotItem>` tags inside your `DataTemplate`, you don't need them.

Comment: Neat, unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue. But thanks anyway - less code is better code